# Seperate GC log file for each Java VM on a Oracle Application Server

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, logging

We have an Oracle AS 10.1.3.4 running 1 application on multiple JVMs. We have set up garbage collection logging using the *-Xloggc* parameter.

However, the gc logging of both JVMs is sent to the same log file. We'd like to get this logging in different log files. Anyone got an idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have control over the JVM arguments of each JVM? I guess the `-Xloggc` which you have set is getting applied for both the JVM's hence the situation. Do you have an admin console where you can view each JVM of your cluster? If yes, you can change the JVM properties for each JVM to log the GC activity to a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you put something unique in your filename? Is there any parameter you pass into the JVMs that you can use to differentiate between them?

You could use hostname and a timestamp but it is not very nice:

```
-Xloggc:/path/to/gc-$HOSTNAME-$(date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S%N).log
```

Comment: That would be great, but the parameter is only specified once and as far as I know there's no way to differentiate between the JVMs. Hostname and timestamp wo'nt work, since they run at the same machine and are started at the same time.

Comment: The wouldn't be *exactly* the same time. You can use %N (nanoseconds) in your timestamp.